# from one userform to another userform

Tags: excel, vba

i have main user-form 1 which has all the information including list box and when user select the name of the person it will find for duplicate and if user press Yes to duplicate msgbox another user-form 2 will popup requiring password and if user enters the correct password it will popup another user-form 3 which has comment box to be updated against initial duplicate find..

problem is that it only updates comment on 1st line row on sheet 1 (where the data updates) and NOT the actual duplicate it finds using staff ID number in column G in sheet1. it only finds first line which is within User-form1 listbox not the line you have selected in User-form1.

below it is the code which works fine within User-form1 and however it dose not work of what i wants to work when placed in user-form 3

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim p As Variant
    Dim lCol As Variant
    Dim response As Variant
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jobs_Allocation")
Dim y As Long

Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

If TextBox1 > False Then
  Unload Me
  lCol = frmSelector.lstSelector.List(x, 3)
Set findvalue = Sheet1.Range("G:G").Find(What:=lCol, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not findvalue Is Nothing Then
        adr = findvalue.Address
        Do
           Sheet1.Unprotect Password:="123"
            If findvalue.Offset(0, -1).Value = frmSelector.lstSelector.List(x, 2) Then
                findvalue.Offset(0, 6).Value = Format(Now, "HH:MM:SS")
                findvalue.Offset(0, 7).Value = TextBox1.Value
                y = sh.Range("C" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set findvalue = Sheet1.Range("G:G").FindNext(findvalue)
        Loop While findvalue.Address <> adr
        Set findvalue = Nothing
    End If
End If

If TextBox1.Value > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You must enter the comment", vbCritical, "Error message"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How the variable x has a value before the code arrive in this line `lCol = frmSelector.lstSelector.List(x, 3)` ?

Comment: Hi Karma it is in user form 1. name of the User form 1 is frmselector

Comment: Hi Harin, I'm sorry as I'm stil unable to understand. For example : since you have three userform, in what userform name the `CommandButton1_Click` Sub in your post reside ? If for example that `CommandButton1_Click` code in your post is in the userform named "frmselector", isn't the `Unload Me` in the code causing the "frmselector" gone/close ?

Comment: Hi Karma sorry. commandbutton1_click its placed on Userform3. frmselector(userform1) if duplicate found then msgbox will popup asking Yes/No and if user selects Yes then 2nd user form will open asking for password, if password were entered correcctly then it will open userform3. if userform2 does not enters the password and cancel the userform2 it will go back to frmselector(userform1) to loop through.

Comment: Harin, if the commandbutton1_click sub in your post is on the third UserForm, then maybe the x variable value is lost though it already get the value from frmselector (first UserForm). Here is the step in my side to test it : I make two userform, Userform1 and Userform2. Each UserForm has one TextBox and in UserForm1 there is also one commandbutton with click_code : `x = TextBox1.Value ....... UserForm2.Show`. In the UserForm2 initialize, I put the code : `TextBox1.value = x`. So I launch UserForm1, fill the textbox with number 5. I click the command button to show UserForm2 and...(continue)

Comment: and I'm expecting that 
the UserForm2 textbox will have a 5 value. 
But no, there is no value in the textbox of the Userform2 because x is empty
at the time UserForm2 initialize run.

Next I change the code in commandbutton_click of UserForm1 with just `UserForm2.Show`.
Then in the UserForm2 initialize, the code is : `x = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value ..... Me.TextBox1.value = x`.
So I launch the UserForm1, fill the textbox with number 5,
then click the command button to show UserForm2.
Now the textbox1 in UserForm2 show the value 5.

Comment: Now to check whether your x variable has a value at the time Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() in your third UserForm run: add a code line : `msgbox x` right after code line `Dim y As Long` then put a red dot stop just to the left of that Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() text.  With this red dot stop, right after you click this commandbutton, it will bring you to the vba editor, so then you can do F8 to debug (run step by step) the code. So, do the F8 ... and soon after the yellow highlight pass the `msgbox x` line, it show you the msgbox then see if the msgbox is blank or has a value.

Comment: hi Karma thank you for your time and efforts but would you be able to write me a full code as i am not an expert in this area, i am still learning on vba. i need to "lCol = frmSelector.lstSelector.List(x, 3)" from frmselector(userform1) to pass over to userform3 to work and return back to frmselector (userform1).

Comment: Harin, if you don't mind - could you please paste all the codes which reside in frmselector in your first post? I hope after I see the codes in frmselector, I understand how your x variable get the value.

Comment: Hi Karma, thank you so much. below it is the code placed in frmselector(userform1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry as I'm not helping you thouroghly, but I think you need to do the loop in your CommandButton1_Click which reside in the third Userform.

I give you a very simple simulation which I hope you can implement it to your code.

[image]

From the image above, it's the first userform, in your case it's frmselector.
The listbox is named to lstselector, and (in the image) the selected item is the fourth row. So, the index number is 3, the x value in your case.

I see that to get the lCol value, you do the code :

```
For x = 0 To Me.lstSelector.ListCount - 1
    If Me.lstSelector.Selected(x) Then
        **If Me.txtJob.Value = Value = False Then**
    
            lCol = Me.lstSelector.List(x, 3)
```

So, disregarding the code-line I put in between two asterisk,
based on the image above, we know that the value of the lCol variable is 80.

To get the lCol value (in other words, to get the selected value on the fourth column of the lstselector in frmselector/first_userform) when running the CommandButton1_Click sub of the third userform, we need to do the loop again. Below is the example of the code, which we hope that the code will give lCol value as 80 :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
With frmselector
    For x = 0 To .lstselector.ListCount - 1
    If .lstselector.Selected(x) Then Exit For
    Next
lCol = .lstselector.List(x, 3)
End With
MsgBox "The value of selected selector in frmselector is: " & lCol
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Karma Many thanks as it worked however i have got an another problem is that if i press command button2 on userform2 or Userform3 then i need to skip userform 2 and 3 and go back to frmselector to contiune to loop without adding the data. i only wants data to be added to sheet if press ok on commandbutton 1 for useroform 1 and 2.